# My label do not show after the layer added in the self.view but View Hierarchy show

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, layer

I drag my labels to my self.view in storyboard, you can see the white labels, in the gray vc, I am sorry for the tiny distinction to found :

[image]

Then I add a gradual layer use code :

```
    let fromColor = UIColor.init(red: 243/255.0, green: 143/255.0, blue: 30/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let centerColor = UIColor.init(red: 237/255.0, green: 90/255.0, blue: 36/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let toColor = UIColor.init(red: 233/255.0, green: 28.0/255.0, blue: 36/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor

    gradul_layer = CAGradientLayer.init()
    gradul_layer?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 64, width: initFrame.width, height: initFrame.height)
    gradul_layer?.colors = [
        fromColor,
        centerColor,
        toColor
    ]
    gradul_layer?.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.3)
    gradul_layer?.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.7)

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradul_layer!)
```

And then when I run my app in simulator (or device) can not show the label, but I can capture the View Hierarchy in Xcode, and I can see the label.

[image]

You see the picture, left is simulator(the labels did not show), right is the capture View Hierarchy(the labels shows up).

---

**Update**

My question is not how to let the label show in my screen, my doubt is why View Hierarchy show, my device or simulator will not.

Comment: Try `self.view.bringSubviewToFront` with that label

Comment: change your label Hierarchy at top

Comment: @Dili, `removeFromSuperlayer` for what?

Comment: @aircraft: Are you not adding the label programmatically? I did one that way and it shows up fine.

Comment: is your label on the view you are adding or on the viewcontrollers view itself? your view with the gradient layer is fine, you cant hide any UIView (Label, Button ....) Item behind a layer of a view if its not already underneath it. If you cant find the problem, just delete the label and add it again, maybe you will get to the point of failure yourself.

Comment: @aircraft: All you need is `self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradul_layer, at: 0)` instead of `self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradul_layer)`, then your label should be on top.

Comment: x-code bug, Once in my project, there is white view appeared in tableview footer then I debugged it by view hierarchy and i found its image view but I don't use any `UIImageView` in my entire project.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy? is it ? I think maybe it is because layer's property , maybe Xcode can not hierarchy out the layer, but can hierarchy the view

Comment: In worst case you can Delete your label and try same by taking new label from storyboard and confirm your label is not hidden.

Comment: did you find an answer? i am ahving exact same problem

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I replace the layer to uUIView.

Comment: from @I'L'I comment on your post i did this self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradul_layer, at: 0)